# Node.js Code not working as expected and PUSHING THE OBJECT TWICE IN THE ARRAY?

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, ejs, body-parser

I am trying to make a Blog Website and for that in `app.post("/compose", function() {})` line when I push the object containing data by the user into the array namely posts defined globally and whenever I console.log the array I get output of array twice instead once. How am I suppose to rectify it?

`//jshint esversion:6`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');

const homeStartingContent = 'Lacus vel facilisis ...';

const aboutContent = 'Hac habitasse platea dictumst ...';

const contactContent = 'Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium...';

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

let posts = [];

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('home', {
        homePageContent: homeStartingContent,
        listContent: posts,
    });
});

app.get('/about', function (req, res) {
    res.render('about', { aboutPageContent: aboutContent });
});

app.get('/contact', function (req, res) {
    res.render('contact', { contactPageContent: aboutContent });
});

app.get('/compose', function (req, res) {
    res.render('compose');
});

app.post('/compose', function (req, res) {
    let post = {
        newTitle: req.body.postTitle,
        newContent: req.body.blogContent,
    };

    posts.push(post);

    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000');
});
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:
[output containing 1 array for 1 entry by user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42ORa.png)

ERROR OUTPUT:
[output containing 2 arrays for 1 entry by user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EDOv.png)

Comment: it shows the output of two console.log, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Every thing looks fine,but try adding in array using spread operator

```
posts = [...posts,post]
```

Or you can try one more way

```
posts[posts.length]=post
```

Comment: I guess the problem is with res.redirect('/'); inside app.post('/compose', function (req, res) { . As when I do   

res.render('home', {
      homePageContent: homeStartingContent,
      posts: posts
  });

It then does not show the to consecutive outputs like before. But, then the code will not be able redirect to root page...